# Partition expiration for a table in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Is it possible to set an expiration date on a partition for a table in Azure Synapse Analytics?  For example, I have a table partitioned on a date column and I want my table to retain only partitions for a week.  Is it possible to discard old partitions which are older than a week automatically in Azure Synapse Analytics?